# HTML Form validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script validating my HTML form, I have it to where if an input is left blank it'll put a "*" next to the labels. I'm having a hard time getting this to work. My goal is to put a * only if the user hasn't filled out any of the inputs. If for example, the name isn't filled out, then all of the labels will have a * next to it. It works for the first label, but the other three don't work.

Heres my formvalidate.js

```
function validateForm(){
        var x = document.forms['Form']
    ['name'].value;
        if (x == "") {
            document.getElementById("v_name").innerHTML = "Name <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
            return false;
        }
    ['email'].value;
        if (x == "") {
            document.getElementById("v_email").innerHTML = "Email <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
            return false;
        }
    ['subject'].value;
        if (x == "") {
            document.getElementById("v_subject").innerHTML = "Subject <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
            return false;
        }
    ['message'].value;
        if (x == "") {
            document.getElementById("v_message").innerHTML = "Message <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
            return false;
        }
}
```

Heres my contact.html form

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/formvalidate.js"></script>
<form class="contact_form" name="Form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" onsubmit="alert('Yeet')" action="contactform.php" method="post">
    <label id="v_name">Name</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="wd" placeholder="Full Name"><br/>
    <label id="v_email">Email</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="a" placeholder="Email"><br/>
    <label id="v_subject">Subject</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="b" placeholder="Subject"><br/>
    <label id="v_message">Message</label><br/>
    <textarea type="text" name="message" id="c" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you think `['email'].value;` is doing? It does not change `x`. Needs to be `x = document.forms['Form']['email'].value;` better yet, do not reuse x, but define other variables.

Answer (score 0):

You're not reassigning value of x properly..

```
function validateForm(){
        var x = document.forms['Form']['name'].value;
        if (x == "") {
            document.getElementById("v_name").innerHTML = "Name <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
            return false;
        }
    x = document.forms['Form']['email'].value;
        if (x == "") {
            document.getElementById("v_email").innerHTML = "Email <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
            return false;
        }
    x = document.forms['Form']['subject'].value;
        if (x == "") {
            document.getElementById("v_subject").innerHTML = "Subject <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
            return false;
        }
    x = document.forms['Form']['message'].value;
        if (x == "") {
            document.getElementById("v_message").innerHTML = "Message <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
            return false;
        }
}
```

Also, functionality like this can be easily achieved using libraries like jQuery. I suggest you look those up.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way to grab the values of different input element like **name**, **email**, **subject** and **message** to js variable and do a check for `undefined` and `not empty`. Also you've some unnecessary unused code inside your `validateForm()` function just remove those e.g `['email'].value;`,`['subject'].value;` and so on then you're good to go. :)

```js
function validateForm() {

  var name = document.forms['Form']['name'].value;
  var email = document.forms['Form']['email'].value;
  var subject = document.forms['Form']['subject'].value;
  var message = document.forms['Form']['message'].value;

  if (typeof name != undefined && name == "") {
    document.getElementById("v_name").innerHTML = "Name <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
    return false;
  }

  if (typeof email != undefined && email == "") {
    document.getElementById("v_email").innerHTML = "Email <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
    return false;
  }
  if (typeof subject != undefined && subject == "") {
    document.getElementById("v_subject").innerHTML = "Subject <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
    return false;
  }

  if (typeof message != undefined && message == "") {
    document.getElementById("v_message").innerHTML = "Message <span class='asterick'>*</span>";
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/formvalidate.js"></script>
<form class="contact_form" name="Form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" onsubmit="alert('Yeet')" action="contactform.php" method="post">
  <label id="v_name">Name</label><br/>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="wd" placeholder="Full Name"><br/>
  <label id="v_email">Email</label><br/>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="a" placeholder="Email"><br/>
  <label id="v_subject">Subject</label><br/>
  <input type="text" name="subject" id="b" placeholder="Subject"><br/>
  <label id="v_message">Message</label><br/>
  <textarea type="text" name="message" id="c" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```